# Вывести текст по щелчку мыши

Tags: javascript

Имеется поле ввода input, в которое вводится текст. Также есть поле вывода output. Необходимо, чтобы по щелчку мышкой в поле output, в него помещался текст из input. Подскажите как реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

То что на ум сразу пришло:

```
 onFocus="this.value=document.getElementById('input').value"
```